# Get mapStateToProps route params from react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I am using react native and redux. I want to create button with navigation param e.g:

```
<Button
    title="Manage Course"
    onPress={() => {
      navigation.navigate('Manage Course', { itemId: 86});
    }}
  />
```

**Other Screen Page:**

```
function ManageCoursePage({....}){
  useEffect(() => { 
    .....
  })
}
.....
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) { 
 // get ownProps itemId param from navigation? 
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ManageCoursePage)
```

so how to send navigation params to ownProps in mapStateToProps function?

Could you please help to resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of react-navigation are you using?

Comment: `"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.5.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.4.1",`

Comment: Then you can use "ownProps.route.params" to get the navigation params

Comment: I tried `ownProps.route.params` but it says undefined

Comment: Are you sure, this is screen name "Manage Course"? Can you also console check what is on the ownProps?

Comment: Yes. I have made a sample snake with that issue on expo. I am sending you an url expo. Please check it on the link
https://snack.expo.io/@adnan.salah84/navigation-mapstatetoprop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the params passed by navigate function using `ownProps.route.params`

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) { 
 const {itemId} = ownProps.route.params;
 ...
}
```

UPDATE: based on your snack

You must note that you are not directly rendering the ManageCoursePage as a result of navigation but have an intermediate stack in between which is receiving the route params but doesn't forward it ot the ManageCoursePage and hence you don't see it in the mapStateToPRops

You can forward them like

```
const CourseMangeStack = createStackNavigator()
function ManageCoureStackScreen({route}) {
  // console.log(route);
  return (
    <CourseMangeStack.Navigator>
      <CourseMangeStack.Screen
        name="Manage Course"

      >{
        props => <ManageCoursePage {...props} params={route.params}/>
      }</CourseMangeStack.Screen>
    </CourseMangeStack.Navigator>
  )
}
```

[Check demo snack](https://snack.expo.io/@mayank_shubham/navigation-mapstatetoprop)

Comment: It says `itemId` is undefined!

Comment: can you try ownProps.navigation.state.params

Comment: Yes. I have made a sample snake with that issue on expo. I am sending you an url expo. Please check it on the link
https://snack.expo.io/@adnan.salah84/navigation-mapstatetoprop

Comment: Adding to the above answer, Make sure you have ManageCoursePage as memo or a PureComponent!

Comment: Glad to have helped